# Asymptotic analysis with theta notation involving n factorial

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

If I have an algorithm that runs in log(n^(5/4)!) time, how can I represent this as something log(n)? Is it just I know that log(n!) would be asymptotically equal to nlog(n) but does the (5/4) change anything, and if it does how so?

Answer (score 0):

Good question! As you noted `log(n!) = O(n log n)`. From this it follows that

```
log(n^{5/4}!) = O(n^{5/4} log n^{5/4}) = O(n^{5/4} log n)
```

The last equality follows because `log n^{5/4} = (5/4)*log n`.

So the you can simplify the expression to `O(n^{5/4} log n)`.

The answer is yes, the factor `5/4` in the exponent matters: the function `n^{5/4}` grows asymptotically fast than `n` so you can't ignore it. (This follows from the fact that `n^{5/4}/n = n^{1/4}`, for example.)